# sshfs permission denied but works good with same pem file on a different client host

Tags: ubuntu, sshfs, scientific-linux

I looked at a lot of SO/SE answers already. I feel my solution is close but not quite right yet obviously.

```
[ga@sam ~]$ sshfs -o IdentityFile="my.pem" ga@192.168.1.111:/mnt/fastssd z820fastssd
fuse: failed to exec fusermount: Permission denied
```

SSH works fine though, using this same client host, which proves my pem file is good:

```
[ga@sam ~]$ ssh -X -o ConnectTimeout=604800 -i "my.pem" ga@192.168.1.111
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-139-generic x86_64)
Last login: Mon Nov 26 13:26:50 2018 from 192.168.1.102
ga@ga-HP-Z820:~$ logout
Connection to 192.168.1.111 closed.
```

My client OS on the new client host is a Scientific LInux which is like redhat:

```
[ga@sam ~]$ uname -a
Linux sam 2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 25 08:47:49 CST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The server is ubuntu.  The old client OS is ubuntu, but the hardware is old and failing so I have to abandon it.  Again, the new client OS is scientific linux. I personally own and administrate all 3 hosts.

I already have made a directory for this mount point on the client:

```
[ga@sam ~]$ cd z820fastssd/
[ga@sam z820fastssd]$ ls
[ga@sam z820fastssd]$
```

My host won’t let me edit the fuse.conf file until I add myself to the sudoers file, evidently, or perhaps add myself to the admin group. But of course I”m in the admin group already because I installed linux and it’s my personal computer.

Saw some advice to put stuff into file fuse.conf.  THere’s no fuse.conf file yet.

```
[ga@sam ~]$ cat /etc/fuse.conf
cat: /etc/fuse.conf: No such file or directory


[ga@sam ~]$ sudo gedit /etc/fuse.conf
[sudo] password for ga:
ga is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

[1]+  Stopped               sudo gedit /etc/fuse.conf
[ga@sam ~]$ su
Password:
[root@sam ga]# gedit /etc/sudoers

[ga@sam z820fastssd]$ cd /etc/sudoers.d
bash: cd: /etc/sudoers.d: Permission denied
[ga@sam z820fastssd]$ sudo cd /etc/sudoers.d
[sudo] password for ga:
ga is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
[ga@sam z820fastssd]$ su
Password:
[root@sam z820fastssd]# cd /etc/sudoers.d
[root@sam sudoers.d]# ls
[root@sam sudoers.d]#
```

There’s no sudoers file, in the directory sudoers.d. So I put ga in the sudosers file while in root:

```
suders.d# Echo “ga” > sudoers
```

Still can’t sshfs:

```
[ga@sam ~]$ sshfs -o IdentityFile="my.pem" ga@192.168.1.111:/mnt/fastssd z820fastssd
fuse: failed to exec fusermount: Permission denied
```

The sshfs works good when using the same pem file and same sshfs command when i run it at another client host of mine, which is ubuntu.  What should I do to get ssfhs to work good as a client, which is scientific linux?

Thanks for reading. LEt me know what else you need to see.

Update:  sftp to the remote host is good. Can someone suggest a solution?  What might be causing the error?  WHich host, remote host or the client host, that is rejecting the attempt, and how exactly would I ascertain?

Comment: Does the `sftp` to the remote host work?

Comment: sshfs -o IdentityFile="my.pem" ga@192.168.1.111:/location/you/want/mounted /full/path/to/where/to/mount

Comment: @MichaelProkopec permission denied when i used full path to where to mount, which in my case was /home/ga/z820fastssd

Comment: Is the username the same on the other client host, you speak of. e.g. ga

Comment: @MichaelProkopec Yes it's the identical username which exists on all three computers.  However there's no central coordination of usernames and so these are all locally defined usernames to each computer.  Group membership is what I'm thinking needs fixing. The remote dir has owner permissions but no group or world permissions, which worked good when the other computer was the client for some reason.

Comment: Not sure if that is what is causing this issue, if the other computer works. I would compare the config files of the computer with the working fusermount to those of the one with the non-working fusermount.

Comment: @MichaelProkopec Which config file should I review?

Comment: @Jakuje sftp to the remote host is good.

Comment: The sshd_config on the host and the ssh_config on the clients and be sure to compare the two clients ssh_configs. Working vs the non-working one.